# Laravel Airlock vs Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-airlock

Can i get posts, or create new posts with [Laravel Airlock](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/airlock) tokens, or for create or updated any rows in database i need use [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#introduction)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this great post : https://divinglaravel.com/authentication-and-laravel-airlock

The last part gives you the answer as well :) but please read it fully, it will clear things up for you.

and yes, you can use `Airlock` only not need to `Passport`

---

Comment: Looks like your answer is copy paste from laracasts discussion. :D :)

Comment: Copied from https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/difference-between-passport-and-airlock . Almost word for word.